# What does "her" at the end of a sentence mean?

Tags: word-order, grammar-identification

> Jetzt ist das fünf Jahr her.

I found this sentence in a documentary I was seeing. What does "her" at the end mean? What grammatical object is it?

Some source say it is adverb, if so, shouldn't it be right after "ist?"

Comment: What remains unclear [after consulting a dictionary?](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/her#Adverb_4)

Comment: If tahat is an adverb, then why did it go to the end? Shouldn't adverb be close to verb @infinitezero

Comment: But it is. **The V2 rule is the last rule applied.** So from the view of all other word order rules, the conjugated verb is at the end of the clause. Compare a dependent clause: *… weil das jetzt fünf Jahre her **ist.***

Comment: Close voters: Since the question asks about word order, it cannot be answered by a dictionary. Also, many dictionaries do not make explicit that the construction is idiomatic (the English Wiktionary linked above is a great example; simply saying that *her* means *ago* would imply that *fünf Jahre her war ich noch in der Schule* was acceptable).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Duden has [her sein](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/her_sein) as a multiword expression, which indicates that the combination is idiomatic, i.e. not derivable from general rules alone.

*Her* combines with a temporal accusative or *lang(e)* to form the subject complement of *sein*:

> **Lange her** ist das nicht.
> *This wasn't long ago.*

> obwohl das schon wieder **einen Monat her** ist
> *although this was a month ago*

Note that the verb is in present tense.

As far as word order is concerned, subject complements generally tend to appear "at the end"; see for instance the section "I.e. The Predicate Nominative and Predicate Adjective" in the article on [word order in main clauses](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/WordOrder/MainClauses.html) at Dartmouth (*predicative* here means the same as *subject complement*).

As Janka points out, this position "at the end" is to be considered "close to the verb" in German. This is shown by verb-final clauses such as the example with *obwohl* above, or when a modal is added in a main clause.

> Das muss jetzt aber wirklich schon **lange her** gewesen sein.
> *But that must really have been a long time ago.*

Comment: Still studying ideas from the site. First time I am encoutnering concepts you mentioned (idk how I even got this far without ever being aware about these stuffs lol)

Comment: In the last sentence you wrote, how would the word order change if you dropped the her?

Comment: Leaving out *her* would completely change the meaning. If *lang* can be interpreted as the subject complement, it will remain at the right: *das Meeting muss aber wirklich lang gewesen sein*. If *lang(e)* is an adverbial of time, it will appear further to the left: *er muss aber wirklich lange krank gewesen sein* (with *krank* as the subject complement). Note that word order in these instances does not depend on part of speech, but on the syntactic function (subject complement vs. adverbial).

Answer (score 5):

It's an adverb of time, similar to *since* in English.

> *Jetzt ist das fünf Jahre **her**.*

> *It has been five years **since**.*